# Quads from a CONSTRUCT query in Jena

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, semantic-web, apache-jena

I'm trying to execute a SPARQL CONSTRUCT query against either a local TDB or a remote SPARQL endpoint. Now `execConstruct` on the `QueryExecution` returns a `Model`, which has no reference (that I know of) to any graph (and thus quads).

Is there a way to get quads from a construct query in Jena? 
I've seen references to `execConstructDataset` but it's not implemented in Jena 3.0 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grammar extension and `QueryExecution` operations `execConstructDataset` , `execConstructQuads` are post-jena 3.0.0.  They are in the current codebase and development builds.

Comment: Are they deployed to Maven somewhere? Also will this allow me to do execConstructDataset on remote SPARQL endpoints?

Comment: Snapshots are available in the Apache snapshot repo.  Snapshots are not releases and have not been as tested or checked. The only remote endpoint supporting it is the development Fuseki2 build.  This is a language extension.

Comment: I guess its's a bit premature to be using the SNAPSHOTS `QueryExecException Attempt to CONSTRUCT quads from a CONSTRUCT query, which is not ARQ Syntax  org.apache.jena.sparql.engine.QueryExecutionBase.execConstructQuads (QueryExecutionBase.java:269)`

Comment: That's because the query was parsed as as SPARQL 1.1, not with ARQ extensions. Could you send a full example to the users@jena list?

Comment: Simply calling execConstructQuads is only going to get you quads for triples in the default model of some dataset.  What are you looking for when you say "no reference to any graph"?

Comment: The specific exception is code that should have been removed and now has.  You can call `execConstructQuads` if you want.